# How do I implement dynamic reloading in Spring (Netbeans)?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, deployment, gradle

I'm used to writing Grails applications where my view or controller changes are automatically redeployed on save. I'm now stringing together a Spring Web-
MVC application and I'd like the same feature.

I'm using Netbeans as an IDE, Gradle as a build tool and the spring-boot plugin at the moment. I remember some talk of people using Jetty as it's so quick to restart that dynamic class reloading / deployment is no longer necessary. I've heard others mention JRebel which I used to use a few years back. I'm sure there is a more modern, spring-supported / spring-standard way of doing it.

I'd also like to know if you recommend deploying as a WAR or as a standalone executable JAR with a lightweight built-in web server.

Recommendations appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A yet unsolved challenge**

It turns out that the Netbeans Gradle plugin does not support "compile on save" out-of-the box - and this means that a Java Agent won't be able to pick up the changes. The author kelemen suggested one or two approaches around this. It's a non-negotiable for me, so I decided to switch IDE's to Eclipse (terrible Gradle support), then IntelliJ Idea - which is looking very promising.

Netbeans Gradle Author Comment: https://github.com/kelemen/netbeans-gradle-project/issues/183

Alternatively, there is Jrebel, which is claimed to be able to support this Netbeans / Gradle combination. I wasn't able to get it working easily using a trial of JRebel. The JRebel support guys are there to help, so if you're willing to pay the price, it's likely that their support team will solve your problems.

JRebel: http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/

If anything changes, please comment below...

Comment: Their support team will be willing to figure it out even if you don't buy the licenses. Send the problem description to support@zeroturnaround.com or write at the dedicated forum - they will check it out!

Comment: I've switched over to IntelliJ Idea with SpringLoaded, and although IntelliJ doesn't compile-on-save, there is a little build button that runs pretty quickly and compiles the files (then picked up by SprintLoaded), allowing a fairly rapid reload. Apparently the new IntelliJ (14.1 in EAP at the moment) has added support for Spring Boot. Not sure if this includes additional support for loaded, but I'm pretty happy with my current Idea solution.

Answer (score 1):

Spring class reloading is supported by [HotswapAgent](https://github.com/HotswapProjects/HotswapAgent) as well. It is free alternative to JRebel.

Comment: This looks quite promising!

Answer (score 0):

Spring has their own agent as well: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded. While developing why not just use embedded Tomcat/Jetty provided by Spring Boot.

Comment: Hi @Vaelyr, any ideas how to use with Gradle / Netbeans?

Comment: Running it doesn't matter what IDE or build tool you're using. Just download the jar, add the java agent to your path when launching application and that's it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTrNkhVnJBU

Comment: Hi @Vaelyr, I haven't found a place in Netbeans to add VM arguments. Any further ideas?

Comment: It really depends how you launch your application. If it`s through IDE or gradle task, you should find anywhere from Google how to add vm args. That's very common thing.